# How to pass constructor as callback

Tags: php

I'm trying to use array_map to map the array to actual instances of my class.

```
class Pet {

    private $petName;

    public function __construct($args) {
        $this->petName = $args['petName'];
    }

}

$array = [['petName' => 'puppy'], ['petName' => 'kitty']];

$instances = array_map([Pet::class, '__construct'], $array);
```

However it ends in error:
`non-static method Pet::__construct() cannot be called statically`

Is it possible to pass constructor call as callback (beside wraping it in closure)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructors aren't intended to be called directly, they're called in a special way by the `new` operator.

So provide a function that uses `new`.

```
public static function makePet($args) {
    return new Pet($args);
}
```

Then use

```
$instances = array_map([Pet::class, 'makePet'], $array);
```

Answer (score 10):

Because it isn't the constructor that creates a class instance; the constructor is simply a block of code in the class that is magically called when a class instance is created using `new`; so all you're doing is trying to call a non-static method of a class statically, which is the problem.

```
$instances = array_map(function($args) { return new Pet($args); }, $array);
```

is the only practical way of doing this